# Google Ads not visible on end pages of website?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, adsense

I have developed an website in **codeigniter** and **angularjs**. Its an news website which has articles in it. I have embedded **google ads** in it which can be seen on home page

Below is the home page url on which you can see ads configured and are viewable. https://pcbtoday.in

But when we open any detail news, ads are `not visible` on that page even if the ads are placed similar to home page 
https://pcbtoday.in/NewsDetail/22451

Also Ads are visible on listing page https://pcbtoday.in/#/newslist/2

Can any one help me out with what I have missed out from the detail page for which the ads are not visible

Comment: Is the google ad code actually on these pages where its not showing... Don't guess - look at the html source code for those pages in your browser. What is different to those than those that are generated where it does work?

Comment: Yes the code is present on the page I crossed verified it again.  You can check the url mention in question main page has google ads whereas detail page doesnt

Comment: So it works in Angular Pages but not in Non Angular pages. Have a look in the console output in your browsers development tools... Usually its F12 to get that up.